# Approximation for Elliptic Integral of the first and second kind

Tags: matlab, math, integral

I am running a program in MATLAB in which I need to solve a first and third kind elliptic integral about 30 million times. Is there an approximation or way to solve it faster than using the built in elliptic integral function? I know there may be a margin of error, but it might be negligible for my purposes.

Comment: You'd be better off parallelizing instead of looking for a new function.

Comment: @duffymo I am not familiar with parallelizing, but each integral requires knowing what the last integral was. Will this provide a problem if I try to run it in parallel?

Comment: Parallelization means that each one is independent of all the others.  If the previous integral needs to know about the previous one, then you can't parallelize.  30 million evaluations in series is going to take a lot of time no matter what approximation you find.  Don't know if these help: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-103/S0025-5718-1968-0226825-3/S0025-5718-1968-0226825-3.pdf